# Executing UFT GUI tests via LeanFT

Tags: automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft, gui-testing, leanft

Our team has already developed bunch of tests (both API and GUI) using UFT. 
I am currently developing a LeanFT project as an Execution engine for all GUI and API tests.
Regarding UFT API tests there is no issue as we are proveded with APITestRunner but for existing UFT GUI tests, I have no idea how to run them from my LeanFT project. 
P.S. I am not interested in converting UFT GUI tests to their LeanFT peers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, running UFT GUI tests from LeanFT tests is not supported. The main reason is that UFT's and LeanFT's runtime engines cannot live side by side. As you mentioned, running UFT **API** tests from LeanFT **is** supported.